# How to provide a plug-in model where different plug-ins take different parameters

Tags: java, plugins, interface, dependency-injection

The code I'm writing (`MyService`) includes the ability for each customer to plug-in their own calculator at a particular point in the processing.  This is to allow customization of business rules.  At the point the calculation is done we know a variety of things, some of which may be relevant to the calculation.  `MyService` will be created for a particular set of input parameters and run once.

My plan is to use dependency injection to give `MyService` a `calculator` in the constructor.  This allows different users to plug-in their own `calculator`.  The `calculator` will return an amount representing the surcharge payable for this particular run of `MyService`.  Others will be implementing a variety of calculators and I'll need to be able to update my code without breaking theirs. ie. keep backwards compatability.

The problem I have is that the various calculator implementations will require different parameters.  These parameters can not be constructor injected into the calculator at the time `MyService` is created because they are not known some processing in `MyService` occurs.

The calculator will only be called once within a particular instantiation of `MyService`.  Therefore at one extreme all parameters could be passed in the constructor and there is a method with no parameters that returns the answer.  At the other, all parameters are passed in the method invocation.

`AlwaysZeroCalculator` might just `return 0` so no parameters are required.  `PercentageCalculator` needs `amount` in order to apply a percentage.  A yet more complicated one needs the `amount` and `customerNumber`.  We can assume that whatever the `calculator` might need is known to `MyService` at runtime (or itself can be injected into the `calculator` implementation, like a hibernate Session).

How can I implement this?

Here are some options and problems:

- Make all calculators implement an interface that includes all parameters as method arguments. But, if something extra is added then they all need to change which will inevitably turn this into the second option.
- Make different interfaces (`ICalculator`, `ICalculatorWithAmount`, `ICalculatorWithAmountAndCustomerNumber`, etc).  `MyService` will need to see which interface the `calculator` it has implements, cast it to that interface, and then call the appropriate `calculate(..)` method.
- Introduce a parameter object that includes anything any of them care about.  This means even the simplest `calculator` depends on everything.
- Make different interfaces and different versions of `MyService` that expect one of those interfaces.
- Inject a `calculatorFactory` instead of a `calculator`.  The factory would take all possible parameters and create a calculator with only the right ones. This seem to just move the problem to somewhere else without solving it.
- Pass some horrible hashmap to the calculator and type safety, declaration of dependencies be damned

Is there a better way?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're talking about information needed to *construct* a calculator, or information needed to *use* a calculator. In particular, this seems to change between different points...

Comment: This is one of the things I'm struggling with.  Should these variable parameters be constructor arguments or method arguments?  The information needed to constructor the calculator is not known at the time MyService is constructed so if the Calculator is constructed and passed in, they must be method arguments.

Comment: @WW: Not with most DI frameworks. You should just take in a Calculator, and pass it whatever arguments are required to perform a calculation, not to *create* a calculator.

Comment: @Jon: Herein lies the problem, the different calculators require different parameters.  These values are not known at the time MyService is created.

Comment: @WW: You're still being unclear about whether they require different parameters *for the method call* or *for construction*. It's an incredibly important distinction, but you keep glossing over it.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify in the question.  The calculator will only be called once for a particular instance of MyService.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @WW: It's still not very clear though - because normally the DI container would be responsible for handling different calculators being *constructed* differently, but they'd still need to have a common interface to be *used* by your class.

Comment: @Jon: I think we're going around in circles here because the bit you are saying is unclear is the reason I'm asking the question.  I'm not sure if the parameters should be passed in the constructor or the method call.

Comment: @WW: It should be clear whether a parameter is part of the *calculation* or part of creating the calculator. It sounds like there should be a logical set of inputs to "a calculation", which should be in the interface, and anything else (e.g. "VAT rate for the country") should be part of the constructor parameters, filled in by the DI layer.

Comment: Depending on what they want to plugin, these are all possible methods: calculate() or caculate( amount ) or calculate( amount, customerNumber ) or calculate( amount, state )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two problems:

- using a calculator
- instantiating a calculator

The first one is easy - all calculators do the same thing, can have the same interface.
The latter is the one to solve, since it requires the different parameter for each calculator instance.

From what you listed is the factory the best solution. And it is not moving the problem elsewhere, it is solving the problem. Each factory knows its calculator and knows what parameters it needs. So the factory depends on calculator. Creating a calculator using a factory only creates a dependency on creating a calculator and not its parameters or the calculator itself, it can be part of the factory interface that all the factories implement.

Providing parameters for the factory can be solved by property injection using whatever means you choose - Spring definitely not bad in that.

The application in turn only know how to use a calculator so depends on the general calculator interface and not any particular calculator implementation.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this right: The problem is providing the right constructor arguments to the various Calculators.  So let's make a factory for it.  Now the Calculators are clean and the problem is providing the right values to the factory.  That problem is solved via Spring reflecting some annotations and calling the right setters.  Feels a bit like something is missing in Java; wonder if other languages/paradigms have solved this one.

Comment: re other languages: not really, this is a general design question. It can be solved using DI, perhaps a formal protocol with descripton so that calling party can aqiure the proper construction information at runtime (think eclipse and plugins), perhaps per reflection. What comes right now in mind: invert DI :-) the factory know how to create the constructor and knows the context, so knows how and where to get the proper parameters.

Comment: Maybe the next generation of languages will have DI built in as a fundamental feature like garbage collection was added in the java/C# generation.

Comment: I ended up injecting Provider<Calculator> into MyService.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using spring ...
Perhaps the factory-bean and factory-method attributes of the bean tag may be useful.

Pseudo code ...

```
<bean id="calculator1"
 factory-bean="calculatorFactory"
     factory-method="getAlwaysZeroCalculator">
         <!--AlwaysZeroCalculator args go here --> 
</bean>
<bean id="calculator2"
 factory-bean="calculatorFactory"
     factory-method="getPercentageCalculator ">
         <!--PercentageCalculator args go here --> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always struggle to get runtime dependencies to work with Dependency Injection in an elegant way.

However, I would go for a variation on your "Make different interfaces" plan.

Each calculator would define it's own interface, say `IAlwaysZeroCalculatorParameters`, `IPercentageCalculatorParameters` etc.

Your `MyService` class can then implement all these interfaces, and then pass itself in to each calculator.

There is very little framework overhead to achieve this, and it means that each calculator expresses concisely what it needs. It works very well for me in similar situations, although in your particular case (where you don't have control over the plugins), it means you must release `MyService` every time someone implements a new calculator (so that it can implement the new interface). If required I would probably get round this with some Duck Typing.

Answer (score 0):

This [calculator](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) uses an `abstract` `FunctionAdapter` to evaluate functions by name. Each concrete subclass implements an `eval()` method that takes a variable number of arguments.