# Alternative to overriding with different arguments in java (which is impossible)

Tags: java, oop

Hi I am facing a design problem which I think it should be quite common:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    ...

   public boolean itsOk()
   {
       return true;
   }
   public void execute()      
   { 
       if (itsOk()){
          System.out.println("done");
       }
   }
}
```

I need to be able to override itsOK() function in any subclass inherited from 'Parent' even if arguments are different.

```
public class Example extends Parent
{
    public boolean itsOK(int a)
    {
       if (a==1)      return true;
       else           return false;
    }

}
```

Then when I call execute, I want the subclass' itsOk() method to be invoked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example e=new Example();
    e.execute();
}
```

This works ok if the subclass' itsOk() method has no arguments (like the 'Parent's method), so it's an overriding case, but how can I make it when arguments are different?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562051/how-to-provide-a-plug-in-model-where-different-plug-ins-take-different-parameters

Comment: I know overriding does not work with different arguments, I am just asking for a way to do it. I need a way to ensure that whenever a subclass extends my Parent class, execute() will call the subclass' itsOk() method instead of the parent's, even if that method has different arguments, unless 'itsOK()' is not defined in the subclass, in that case the parent's method will be invoked. If that's impossible, I just will pass an array of strings as an argument (so that array can be empty and also can have variable length)

Comment: In your example call of `execute()`: If it would work that way and the child `itsOK()` gets called, what should happen with its parameter `int a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case I would rather try to have the same method signature in the parent and the child class, ie. a real overwriting and not an overloading. Then, your parameter *a* could be a member of the class Example which would avoid the need for a parameter. Of course it strongly depends on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Call `super.itsOk();` in your subclass' `itsOk` method.

That is, I'm assuming what you mean is you want to have an overload of `itsOk` defined in your subclass which does something new but also invokes the parent class' default implementation of `itsOk`.

As an aside, note the terminology: you're **not** overriding: to do that, the `itsOk` in your subclass **must** have the same method signature as in the parent class. Instead you're **overloading** creating a brand new method that just happens to have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    ...

   public <T> boolean itsOk(T t)
   {
       return true;
   }
   public void execute()      
   { 
       if (itsOk()){
          System.out.println("done");
       }
   }
}

public class Example extends Parent<Integer>
{
    public boolean itsOK(Integer a)
    {
       if (a==1)      return true;
       else           return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: The idea is ok, but this is not going to work. `Example` should extend `Parent<int>` instead of raw `Parent`, but you can't use primitive types such as `int` to fill in type parameters in Java. You should use `Integer` in that case. Also the `itsOk()` call in `Parent` wouldn't automatically call the `itsOk` that takes an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `itsOk(int a)` method in class `Example` is not overriding the `itsOk()` method in class `Parent` - it is an entirely separate method that doesn't have anything to do with the method in class `Parent`.

With what value of `a` do you want `itsOk(int a)` in `Example` to be called when you call `itsOk()` in `Parent`?

You could ofcourse add an `itsOk(int a)` method to class `Parent`; then the version in `Example` would be overriding that version, and in the `execute()` method you could call it:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public boolean itsOk() {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract boolean itsOk(int a);

    public void execute() {
        if (itsOk(0)) {
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
}
```

Without declaring an `itsOk(int a)` method in class `Parent`, you cannot call that method on a `Parent` object (or on an `Example` object, if the type of the variable referring to the object is `Parent`).

I don't think this is a common design problem.

Answer (score 0):

When arguments are different it no longer is a case of Overriding. It is called Overloading which basically means that you have **two distinct** methods to call.